# Wix: Apply property publishing

Tags: installation, wix, windows-installer, wix3.5

My Wix project contains 3 files:

1) **Product.wsx** - main wxs file

2) **MyDlg.wxs** - my custom dialog with checkboxes

3) **1.txt** - any file

**Product.wxs**:

```
  <Media Id="1" Cabinet="media.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />      
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />

  <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
     <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="My" />
     </Directory>
  </Directory>

  <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLFOLDER">
     <Component Id="ProductComponent" Guid="{FC9CE1FD-9BF6-4746-9918-5B2DFA312A2B}">
        <File Id="img" Source="$(sys.CURRENTDIR)1.txt" Name="1.txt" KeyPath="yes" Vital="yes" DiskId="1" />
     </Component>
  </DirectoryRef>

    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="My" Level="1" Absent="allow">
        <ComponentRef Id="ProductComponent" />
     <Condition Level="0">RECOGVERSION = 0</Condition>
  </Feature>

  <UI>
     <UIRef Id="WixUI_Mondo" />
     <UIRef Id="WixUI_ErrorProgressText"/>

     <Publish Dialog="LicenseAgreementDlg" Control="Next" Event="NewDialog" Value="MyDlg" Order="10" >LicenseAccepted = "1"</Publish>
     <Publish Dialog="MyDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg" Order="10">NOT Installed</Publish>
     <Publish Dialog="CustomizeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MyDlg" Order="10">NOT Installed</Publish>
  </UI>
```

**MyDlg.wxs**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
   <Fragment>
      <UI>
         <Property Id="RECOGVERSION" Value="0" Secure="yes" /><br/>

         <Dialog Id="MyDlg" Width="370" Height="270" Title="My empty dialog">

            <Control Id="RecognitionServerText" Type="Text" X="25" Y="53" Width="340" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes" Text="Select version:" />
            <Control Id="RecognitionServerRadioButtonGroup" Type="RadioButtonGroup" X="16" Y="70" Width="120" Height="73" Property="RECOGVERSION" >
               <RadioButtonGroup Property="RECOGVERSION">
                  <RadioButton Height="15" Text="version 1 (old)" Value="0" Width="120" X="0" Y="0" />
                  <RadioButton Height="15" Text="version 2 (new)" Value="1" Width="120" X="0" Y="18" />
               </RadioButtonGroup>
            </Control>

            <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)">
               <Publish Property="RECOGVERSION" Value="0">RECOGVERSION = "0"</Publish>
               <Publish Property="RECOGVERSION" Value="1">RECOGVERSION = "1"</Publish>
               <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomizeDlg" Order="10" />
            </Control>
            <Control Id="Back" Type="PushButton" X="180" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Text="!(loc.WixUIBack)">
               <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlg" Order="10" />
            </Control>
            <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="304" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUICancel)">
               <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
            </Control>

         </Dialog>
      </UI>
   </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

When I try click on "Next" button in my customized dialog then **nothing is happening**.
I cannot go to the next dialog.

I try remove these lines from MyDlg.wxs:

```
<Publish Property="RECOGVERSION" Value="0">RECOGVERSION = "0"</Publish>
<Publish Property="RECOGVERSION" Value="1">RECOGVERSION = "1"</Publish>
```

It has effect but in the new window but there is **not updated value** of "RECOGVERSION" property.

What is the problem?

Comment: Run your msi like this: msiexec /i myprod.msi /l*v install.log The wxs looks correct to me.

Comment: There is extraction from the log: http://pastebin.com/5BWU3rt9

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution**

```
<Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="236" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)">
   <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="CustomizeDlg" Order="10">1</Publish>
   <Publish Property="RECOGVERSION" Value="[RECOGVERSION]" Order="11">1</Publish>
</Control>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the ControlEvent table of your MSI using ORCA.  I'm guessing that because you didn't specify an Order attribute that your order is all wrong and the NewDialog [NEXTDIALOG] is being processed before your augmented ControlEvents have a chance to run.